# How openjfx-11 archive used in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, javafx-9, openjfx

I download the archive openjfx-11-ea+13_windows-x64_bin-sdk and OpenJDK.
Then I create a JavaFX Application project and write a demo in Intellij IDEA (1.8.3).

For Compile the project,in IDEA "Module Setting" ->"Dependencies",I set the "lib" directory as the jars and set the"bin" directory as the"Native Library Locations".

But when I run the Application,console show "javafx runtime components are missing".

I do not know how to use the seprate openjfx with openjdk.

Thank you for ur help

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S and go to libraries and add folders you need. This should work fine.

Comment: I had add "javafx-sdk-11\bin" to the libraries and in the module dependencies,still have the same error when Run.

Comment: you are right,I forgot to add module-info.java in Demo.

Comment: You can also run a non-modular application (i.e. without adding module-info.java). You need to add `--add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml` arguments to your java command.